# Send string char by char between two process using fork

Tags: c++, c, linux, fork

I have this assignment where I have to create a program on C/C++ for linux, where it sends a string char by char from one process to another, and when the second process receives the characters it uppercase them.

This is the code I wrote, if someone can tell me if the sharing process is done right or I'm missing something.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int childpid;
    char *string = "Hello";
    char *letter;

    childpid = fork();

    if(childpid == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i<string.length; i++) {
            letter = string[i];
            printf(letter);
        }
    } else {
        read(letter);
        printf(letter.toupper());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Code update:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pid;
    int mypipe[2];
    int ret;
    char *string = "Hello";
    char *buf[20];
    int bytesread;

    ret = pipe(mypipe);

    if(ret == -1) {
        perro("Pipe failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i<string.length; i++) {
            write(mypipe[1],string[i],1);
        }
    } else {
        while( (bytesread = read(mypipe[0],buf,15)) > 0) 
        {
            buf[bytesread] = '\0';
            printf("buf: %s\n", buf.toupper()); 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to read about [`pipe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) and [`dup2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html).

Comment: You may want to look at unix pipes. Type `man 2 pipe` in a terminal.

Comment: Your update looks basically ok.  (1) `read` in loop.  You'll probably be ok in this toy example but you are not guaranteed to get your entire read request in one call.  (2) close your pipe ends.  It's not  just good hygiene, it's how EOF is sent to the other side.

Comment: so i need to run the same loop in the parent process as I did in the child, and inside it read is that what you're saying ?

Comment: along the lines of "while ((bytesread = read(...)) > 0)"

Comment: if you don't read the whole msg in 1 read call you'll need to make buf[bytesread] = '\0'; to null terminate the string before you printf it.

Comment: i've update my code can you check if I did what you said

Comment: I edited your code section rather than try to squash it into a comment.  Your parens were wrong and you need to null terminate the string before printing because if you get a partial read your string could print any existing junk in the buffer until it hits a null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `fork()` the `string` variable is present in parent as well as child process. You are simply making `toupper()` in one of the process. What you are missing is that there is no communication between parent and child. Parent is suppose to pass the char to the child and then the child should make it `toupper()`. As suggested one way to achieve this communication is through `pipe`.

Comment: Can you check my update and tell me if I did it correct.

Comment: It looks good. Your `read` needs to be in loop. Refer [sample](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html). Note how hard coding of third parameter in `read` and `write` is avoided. Also I guess you are writing C program (and not a C++ program). So remove iostream inclusion.